# Rails: Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am relatively new to Rails and I am trying to use the asset pipeline, SCSS, in the development environment. However, after I created the controller, the view, and the `css.scss` file, I encounter the following error:

`Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled`

Here is the error message:

> Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production. Add
>   `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( public.css )` to
>   `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

I read that in development, the assets get compiled on the fly and there is no need to pre-compile. Why is there a pre-compile error? Did Rails think that I am in production instead of development?

Edited on 1 March 2016 ------

I just realized that adding files onto the config/initializers/assets.rb works. But is this the right way to do it? I have to add all the css/js/jpg files manually in the assets.rb for it to work. I felt that this somehow violate the DRY principle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the file

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

> > config.assets.debug = true (if TRUE change to FALSE)

Comment: config.assets.debug is set to True.

Comment: try to change it to FALSE

Comment: It worked. Thanks. So debug mode does not preprocess the assets, that's why i need to set it off? So the scss files require preprocessing to work?

Comment: Welcome! Yes!, since it will takes time when its required to debug in development environment. But in production mode it is set to true, since you need to precompile all assets for faster rendering and interpreting.

Comment: This didn't work for me I am still getting the error, I changed it from true to false

Comment: Yeah, See Ameer's answer. It worked for me in Rails 5.2.5
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203218/3300043

Answer (score 148):

Neither of these worked for me (rails-5.0.7, sprockets-3.7.2, sprockets-rails-3.2.1):

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = true
```

But this *did*:

```
config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false
```

Comment: literally, ```config.assets.check_precompiled_asset``` worked for me too. rails version 4.2.8

Comment: Thank you so much, this also worked for me in Rails 6.0.2.1

Comment: This helped in api only app's issue in Apitome document parsing.

Comment: This worked for me in rails 6.0.3.3 when Sprockets couldn't figure out myfile.js.erb was a thing

Comment: Worked when rails 6 + spina failed out of the box (Oct 2020)

Comment: Worked for me, but why? App suddenly started throwing these errors for images.  Chucking this in development.rb got it working again.

Comment: only this worked for me Rails 5.2.6 (Oct 2021)

Comment: It works. But doesn't this mean, that it will not verify/check precompiled_assets ? Is it a good thing to do?

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand that, but Thanks! It worked for me.

Answer (score 54):

I had the same problem and fixed it by deleting all the cache files inside the tmp folder

```
rm -rf tmp/cache/assets
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!
(rails 5.2.2 / sprockets 4.0.2 / sprockets-rails 3.2.2)

Comment: Thanks! This is the actual solution.`rm -rf tmp/cache/assets/`

Comment: Worked for me with Rails 6.1

Answer (score 30):

```
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

Adding this to  **app/assets/config/manifest.js**
Worked for me (working on rails 6)

Comment: I had to add this two lines to make it work `//= link administrate/application.css
 //= link administrate/application.js` using Rails 6.

Comment: Worked for me with rails `6.1.3`

Answer (score 19):

For those who came here after upgrading from rails 4 to 5-6 - checkout manifest.js

```
app/assets/config/manifest.js
```

If there is no link to js - just add one:

```
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

Answer (score 9):

Changing `assets.debug` did not work for me in Rails v5.1.5. I had to use this option:
`config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = true`

Answer (score 6):

you can initialize this scss file for the following line of code

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( applicationname.css )
```

Comment: file in which above needs to be changed: config/initializers/assets.rb

Answer (score 4):

Try `rake tmp:clear`

References -
https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/458

Comment: bingoding is right! ...that's the sound of relief

Comment: This solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to declare my assets in my manifest:

```
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding here in case it might help someone.

I had a specific JS files I wanted only in a specific ActiveAdmin page and it was under `/app/assets/javascripts/admin/orders`.

Initially, none of the solutions worked for me beside adding this to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false
```

A coworker mentioned that this change is a bit fishy and I tend to agree. Like what are the implications this will have on our development? Will we see errors related to precompilation of assets only in staging / prod from now?

Since I had subdirectories including JS files under my `/app/assets/javascripts` folder, I tried changing

```js
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

to

```js
//= link_tree ../javascripts
```

And it solved it for me.
Without the `config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false` in the `development.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to **app/assets/config/manifest.js**

```
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to restart the app too if you pulled new code.